# ¿Cómo transformar DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE de SQL Server a código Genexus 18?

Tags: sql-server, genexus, encriptación, contraseña

Tengo una consulta en SQL donde utilizo ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE para encriptar contraseñas y
DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE para desencriptarlas.

¿Cómo puedo transformar el ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE/DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE de SQL Server a código Genexus?

Lo que quiero es básicamente recuperar (desencriptar) la contraseña de un usuario, desde Genexus, considerando que su contraseña ya está encriptada por la función SQL mencionada.

Sé que en GX existe Decrypt64()

```
&pass = Decrypt64(&psw, &key)
```

pero al parecer no es el mismo tipo de encriptación y por lo tanto no funciona.

No importa si debo incluir código nativo C#/Java,etc. ¿alguna idea?

Comment: La función cifra datos mediante una frase de contraseña usando el algoritmo TRIPLE DES con una longitud de clave de 128 bits, en versiones anteriores a 2017 y 2017 y posteriores cifran con AES256. Hay implementaciones de estos algoritmos en java y en c#. Debes tener en cuenta, si has usado el parámetro add_authenticator en 1, que junto al texto se cifra un hash (desconozco el algoritmo que usa en ese caso, pero seguro se puede investigar).

Comment: Por que no puedes ejecutar DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE desde Genexus?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Pues porque a lo que tengo entendido en Genexus no existe esa función como tal, he visto que existe CryptoSymmetricEncrypt (algoritmos simétricos), pero es muy complejo porque no es como en SQL en donde se utiliza sólo una &clave y una &key. ¿lo has utilizado en Genexus, podrías compartirme cómo?

Comment: Suponía que Genexus era la aplicación pero los datos los manejabas en SQL Server